# 1902 use of phrase "giving a tiger" in the context of paying homage to the King's coronation

Tags: expressions, british-english, history, australian-english

In Mrs Aeneas Gunn's autobiographical 'The Little Black Princess : *A True Tale of Life in the Never-Never Land*, 1905, she writes about previously celebrating the coronation of Edward VII in the bush.

> As the last few Poolooloomees glided out of sight, we gave a 'hip, hip, hooray!' and a 'Tiger' for King Edward VII, and then amused ourselves by trying to fire some more...

and, later,

> ... the men gave another 'Hip Hooray and a Tiger' for the King, and then fired a volley of revolver shots into the air as a royal salute.

*A Tiger* sounds as though it is more likely an English term than an Australian one. I am anxious  to find out the definition and any other information about what a *Tiger* is in this context. Can anyone please help?

(A *Poolooloomee* is a local Indigenous fire-work like amusement).

Comment: Appreciated Mari-Lou A

Answer (score 2):

Interesting! I'd not come across this before. According to the OED, it is (or was):

> *U.S. slang.* A shriek or howl (often the word ‘tiger’) terminating a prolonged and enthusiastic cheer; a prolongation, finishing touch, final burst.

1845 onwards.

["tiger, n." OED Online. Oxford University Press, September 2014. Web. 21 November 2014.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/201910)

Answer (score 1):

The idiom is explicitly "three cheers and a tiger", for special occasions when the normal 'three cheers' was or is not exuberant enough. [Wordreference](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1186094) seems to think it originated in the American Civil War, as a low growl reaching a crescendo; [Straight Dope](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=13609) accords more with the British experience, of a fourth cheer becoming an enthusiastic babble.

Comment: As said by Jim Backus' genie in A-Lad-In his Lamp: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7ZzKGvcmWs#t=6m31s